# How to disable SSL for old device

Tags: wordpress, ssl, webserver, cloudflare

I have a problem on my website I have add cloudflare free SSLon WordPress site and its works perfectly but I have a big problems with old devices like win XP or android above 3 it doesn't work on these devices
So I want to ask you can I disable SSLfor old devices ?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare uses a technology called SNI to issue SSL at scale on their Free plan, this is what fundamentally rules out support for HTTPS on Windows XP SP2 and Android <3.0.

The most sensible option here is to use a Cloudflare Pro or Business plan as this limitation doesn't appear on those plans.

Whilst you could try using some logic to check a users browser before redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, this falls over when sites like Google link to the SSL version of your website and those users cannot load the page, making this solution impractical.

Further reading:

- [What browsers work with CloudFlare's SSL certificates?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203041594-What-browsers-work-with-CloudFlare-s-SSL-certificates-)